# Передача объекта вызванного класса в метод

Tags: c#

Делаю одну фишку для игры. В общем, есть парочка классов:

```
public class process_api(){
    public void attach_to_process(String name_process){

        //Прикрепляем программу к процессу игры
    }
}

public class Person(){

    public float get_x_pos()
     //Читаем память процесса
    }
}
```

Суть в том, что при создании новых объектов класса - нужно заново прикреплять их к процессу, что забивает оперативку. Как можно прикрепить к процессу в одном классе, а работать с этим "прикрепленным" объектом во многих

Comment: Нужны пояснения. Создания новых объектов какого класса происходят? Я правильно понимаю что вы хотите единственный экземпляр класса `process_api` для всей программы?

Comment: @Gordory, да. Нужен 1 объект класса process_api использовать во всей программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После пояснений стало ясно что здесь речь пойдет о паттерне проектирования Singleton (одиночка). Этот паттерн нужен для того чтобы во время исполнения программы гарантировано был только один экземпляр класса.

Почитать про этот паттерн можно [тут](https://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern).

Теперь дальше. В вашем случае сложные реализации не особо нужны, потому что ваш класс `ProcessApi` пока не зависит от других классов.

Стоит посмотреть в сторону ключевого слова `static`. А также не забыть, что если у вас будет параллельный доступ к классу `ProcessApi`, то нужно использовать `lock`-и для того чтобы избежать всяких неприятных штук, типа [Race Condition](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)